# Anagram code meaning

Tags: java, arraylist, anagram

In the below code, what is the meaning of the following line?

```
m.put(alpha, l=new ArrayList<String>());
```

Code (for finding Anagrams):

```
try {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
    while (s.hasNext()) {
        String word = s.next();
        String alpha = alphabetize(word);
        List<String> l = m.get(alpha);
        if (l == null)
            m.put(alpha, l=new ArrayList<String>());
        l.add(word);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println(e);
    System.exit(1);
}
```

Comment: depends on what `m` is. If you're confused by assignment as function argument, please keep in mind that in Java assignment is an operator, just like `+`. Its result is the value being assigned, plus it has a side effect of changing the value of the variable.

Comment: Your full code needs to be here as a [mcve]. But looks like you have a Hashmap. What's not to understand about that?

Comment: In Java 8, that would be `m.computeIfAbsent(alpha, l -> new ArrayList<String>()).add(word);`

Answer (score 3):

The part

```
m.put(alpha, l=new ArrayList<String>());
```

could also be written as

```
l=new ArrayList<String>();
m.put(alpha, l);
```

An assignment returns the assigned value, which is why your code is working.

Comment: ok thanks for this but i want to know what l will contain , value of l is empty array?

Comment: @user3386952 Yes, `l` will contain what is currently in the map, and if it's not in the map, an empty `ArrayList` will be added and `l` will reference it.